# Close printwriter from different class

Tags: java, printwriter

Is it possible to close print writer from different class or is there any other way. What I am trying to do is there is a function "A" which is calling function "B" which calls function "C" and this function "C" is inside a loop. And all "A","B","C" are in different classes. Since print writer is not closed, nothing is being printed. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sharing is always better than explain it, very hard to imagine the situation by reading your text

Comment: The PrintWriter not being closed would not result in nothing being printed.

Comment: (Any code which has a reference to the PrintWriter can call its close method.)

Comment: @azro I'll make the question simpler. If printwriter is initialised in constructor in class "B" and and a method of class "B" is called in class "C" and that method is in a loop. Since I cannot close printwriter in the method, nothing is getting printed into the file. So is there any other way I can get my output?

Comment: @DavidConrad the method which calls close() is main method of class "C" which is not being called anywhere

Comment: Is it also the one that produces the output? Because that would explain why you aren't getting any.

Comment: Please add some sample code to the question to be more precise.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you Mr. David. I found your reply very helpful. Due to that I got my answer. I created a separate method which only closes printwriter. Then I just had to call the new method after the loop in lass "B".

Answer (score 0):

Try making the PrintWriter a class variable, then try closing it from another class.

Comment: Actully I made printwriter into a global variable and for cloasing it I created another method. And just called this method after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I created a different method which closes the printwriter. And then called this method in class "B" after the loop ends.